# Book series about superpowered teenaged clones with tattoos on their heels

Tags: story-identification, books, clones, powers

I remember a lot of the plot except for characters’ names or the series/books names.

Basically a teenage girl learns that her grandfather/caretaker was a scientist who participated in cloning humans and with the help of one of the other scientists hid the clones from the third who was wanting to use them for nefarious purposes as the clones had powers (later revealed that the powers were sorta like genetic overcorrecting of issues; weak body, depleting eyesight, etc).

One way of identifying the clones is a tattoo on the back of their heels; a four digit birthday and a m or f (for their gender). One of the clones, a blonde girl with super strength, was a clone of a supermodel. The clone with super eyesight (yet wore glasses) was close with his foster sister to where she got his tattoo tattooed onto her and that got her kidnapped by people going after the clones.

I also remember that it was in my high school library if that helps.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this book? Also, do you recall any details about the cover?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the ***[Regeneration](https://www.goodreads.com/series/84744-regeneration)*** series by L.J. Singleton.

- Book 1: *[Regeneration](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2051944.Regeneration)* (2000)
- Book 2: *[The Search](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1517904.The_Search)* (2000)
- Book 3: *[The Truth](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1517903.The_Truth)* (2000)
- Book 4: *[The Imposter](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/128248.The_Imposter)* (2000)
- Book 5: *[The Killer](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2051943.The_Killer)* (2001)

The synopsis on the [Google Books page](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Regeneration/GBPaYrmovncC?hl=en) for the first book notes that three scientists created five cloned children, and that two of the scientists had to save the clones from the third:

> Three scientists embark on the ultimate experiment in DNA enhancement. The results? Five cloned children, each created from the genes of a different person, each meant to be perfect. But when the mastermind of the project deems it a failure, the other scientists have to save the clones from his wrath. And now, after fifteen years apart, the teen clones band together to defeat the madman who is still bent on their destruction.

Searching inside the book using the keyword "tattoo" brings up results suggesting that the clones have tattoos on their feet.

> Eric bent down and rolled down one of his socks. Then he pointed at a dark spot on his ankle. "This here tattoo. It's not much bigger than my thumbnail"

A customer review of the fourth book on [this page](https://www.thriftbooks.com/w/regeneration-04-the-imposter_lj-singleton/1343154/#edition=2388635&idiq=3382786) names all five clones, and states that one of them (Eric) has super vision, and another (Allison) has super strength.

> Sandee never trusted or believed anyone but herself. Then the only thing she cared about was taken from her, her music. Sandee seeks help from Chase who she is secretly falling for even though she can't completely trust him. She still doesn't believe that she is a clone considering she has no amazing power like the rest of them. Varina has a super memory, **Eric has super vision, Allison has super strength,** and Chase has super hearing. In the end the five clones band together to get Sandee's music back and to bring the people who stole it to justice.

And the Goodreads synopsis of the fourth book mentions that Allison was the clone of a "gorgeous model." You said a blonde girl with super strength was a clone of a supermodel, so that part especially seems like a perfect match.

> Nothing prepares Allison for the shock of meeting the woman she was cloned from. A gorgeous model, Cressida Ray has no idea that she and her teenage look-a-like share the exact same genes. Allison wonders if she should tell Cressida the truth -- and soon finds that someone will go to great lengths to keep her quiet.